# how to remap key : to go in vim command-line mode?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim, editor, putty

Using a Italian keyboard, to switch to command-line mode from any other mode(normal, insert, visual) I need to (<kbd>ESC</kbd>) ad press key

<kbd>:</kbd>

Because the keyboard aforementioned, the COLON key require pressing TWO keys:

<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd>

There is a way to remap the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> with maybe `<LEADER>` (or a function key <kbd>F1</kbd>) ?
I presume I need some `?map` setting in `.vimrc` but I didn't have success in my tempts.

BTW, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd><kbd>:</kbd> is one of things a bit slow-down editing in `vi`, for me.

thanks

Comment: That's "command-line mode", not "command" mode.

Comment: I corrected. BTW, googling around is see is common to refer command-line mode shortly as command mode.

Comment: Which is sadly a common mistake.

Comment: "Command" mode means that vi will interpret keys presses as commands instead of editing text. `Esc dd` will delete the current line instead of inserting the characters `dd` into the text. "Command line" mode means you can enter a longer command at the bottom of the editor window.

Comment: so "command mode" == "normal mode". Indeed my question refer to "command-LINE mode" :-)

Comment: And I think you have to press Shift + `.` (dot) to get a `:` (colon).

Answer (score 1):

You can choose another key to enter *command-line mode* like this:

```
nnoremap <F1> :
```

I wouldn't recommend `<Leader>` because that would affect most plugin mappings, but you are free to use any other key (cp. `:help key-notation`).

Comment: I see your point abour plugins,. I truied `nnoremap <F1> :` but strangely do not behave correctly (it put in insert mode ?!) instead  `nnoremap <leader> :` seem work fine! thanks.

Comment: Are you in a terminal? Some grab the function keys for their own use, or the `$TERM` may not be set correctly. Anyway, it was just an example, as the function keys typically are quite hard to reach.

Comment: yes, I use putty terminal emulator on a windows host, going into a headless linux ubuntu guest box (containing vim 7.4).